# How can I print a full list of words with nltk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nltk

I have nltk installed and downloaded and running on python. I have checked that it is working with

```
import nltk.corpus import words
print "fine" in words.words()
```

and it printed True.
I would like to have an object list get stored so that I could print the list and see a long series of words. However, when I try printing word.words() or setting a list equal to words.words my computer only loads and never succeeds in the task. I eventually have to force quit. I am aware that about 50,000 words is a lot, but I feel that it should not crash the program. Does nltk not allow you to save as a list or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: Please post a minimal viable example of your code.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wish to print (or do anything actually) with the list's objects, you should probably use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which are runtime iterators which iterate over the iterable objects dynamically and are therefore suited to the task of going over very large data sets.
What you could do might be something like this:

```
def generator(l):
    for i in l:
        yield i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    very_large_list = [1,2,3]
    for i in generator(very_large_list):    # Iterate over the list dynamically without storing in memory
        print i
```